# Creepy dinosaur pc game identification

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember a dinosaur game from when I was little, I probably played it around 1998-2000's. In this game, dinosaurs could speak english and some would dress in clothes. I remember going to visit a female dinosaur with a crown like object around her head, she might have been part of royalty or an ambassador. She stood on 2 feet.

There would be scenes inside a castle and the most vivid part I can remember is going downstairs into this chamber and talking to a really creepy guy. And from there, there was a secret passage way to somewhere lower. It would open into a room that had skeletons in open coffins and I remember the music sounding so scary in this part, that I'd cry and leave the room. I wasn't old enough to think about turning down the music. But now I'd like to play and get past this part.

I also remember there being missions of having to leave and gather ingredients. I'd go into a forest and pick mushrooms. The style of the game was on the realistic side of things (as good as the graphics could get then). It was a first-person view game and I believe you had to click on something to move to different areas.

**Additional info that I remember:**

- There were some humans in the game, I think the king was one. That maybe why I was leaning towards the female dinosaur to be an ambassador of some sort. They were human skeletons in the coffins, and the coffins were vertical, so they looked to be standing inside of them.
- The "crown" that I remember on the female dinosaur was more like a diamond necklace that was laid on her head, like an elegant crown.
- There was a really creepy man in it! He had his tongue cut out so it was really hard to understand him.

Comment: So, were all the characters dinosaurs? Including the player? Related, were the skeletons in the crypt human or dinosaur skeletons?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots There would be some humans, I think the king may have been human. The were human skeletons in the crypt.

Comment: Was this a Yoshi game by any chance?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Very funny! but no.

Comment: Could it be one of the *Dinotopia* games?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Nope, just looked it up. Mine was 1st person view, couldn't see who you were. So there wasn't a top-side view to rooms, you were fully in the room/area/forest.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Lost Eden

From [MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/game/lost-eden):

> Lost Eden is an adventure game set on an eerie planet populated with dinosaurs.
>
> Your civilisation is menaced. Armies of Tyranns, led by Moorkus Rex, are gathering around your kingdom. Soon they will swarm in, destroy everything and kill your people. However, there is a single hope. There are legends telling that several hundreds of years ago, men and dinosaurs cooperated to build 5 mighty Citadels that were almost invulnerable to the Tyranns. Today, all the Citadels but one have been destroyed.
>
> You play as Adam of Mo, you must rediscover the secret of uniting men and dinosaurs, rebuild the Citadels, and finally defeat Morkus Rex and his armies.

---

> PC Game

Released for MS-DOS and Macintosh.

---

> I probably played it around 1998-2000's

Released in 1995.

---

> In this game, dinosaurs could speak english and some would dress in clothes.

[image: Eloi the Pteradactyl Male, Lost Eden]

Although they talk, they don't seem to be wearing clothes (aside from carrying satchels, etc)

---

> I remember going to visit a female dinosaur with a crown like object around her head, she might have been part of royalty or an ambassador. She stood on 2 feet.
>
> There were some humans in the game, I think the king was one. That maybe why I was leaning towards the female dinosaur to be an ambassador of some sort.

The king is a human and your father. When you first met him, he is next to Eloi, a dinosaur messenger from north who stands on two feet, although it doesn't match your description of being a queen or having a crown.

[image: Throne Room, Lost Eden]

---

> There would be scenes inside a castle and the most vivid part I can remember is going downstairs into this chamber and talking to a really creepy guy. And from there, there was a secret passage way to somewhere lower. It would open into a room that had skeletons in open coffins

[This walkthrough](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/565039-lost-eden/faqs/2088) seems to describe your experience, assuming that the "Monk" is the "really creepy guy".

> Go to the Monk's chamber and take a closer look at
> your ancestors.  One  teeth seems to be  missing  and  your
> highness has a teeth from Jabber. Try to put that teeth into
> mummy's mouth. So the secret passage is revealed. Muster all
> your courage and dive to the subterran tunnels. Wait ! Isn't
> it  the dreaded Moorkong bellowing in the darkness beyond  ?
> It might be dangerous but I advice you to go ahead. There is
> a  skeleton guarding your path.

---

> I also remember there being missions of having to leave and gather ingredients. I'd go into a forest and pick mushrooms.

From the same walkthrough:

> Now  you have to find a shaded forest and get some mushrooms from there.

---

> The style of the game was on the realistic side of things (as good as the graphics could get then). It was a first-person view game and I believe you had to click on something to move to different areas.

As you can see from the above screenshots, this game seems to describe your experience.

---

You can get more info about this game at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Eden) or [Moby Games](https://www.mobygames.com/game/lost-eden)

It's also available for purchase on both GOG.com and Steam!

(For reference, the way I found out about this was that I guessed that a realistic, first-person game in the 90s was an adventure game, and [I queried Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=deepcat%3A%22Adventure+games%22+deepcat%3A%22Dinosaurs+in+video+games%22&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22deepcategory%22%3A%5B%22Adventure+games%22%2C%22Dinosaurs+in+video+games%22%5D%7D%2C%22namespaces%22%3A%5B0%5D%7D&ns0=1) for all pages that were tagged with both the categories "Adventure games" and "Dinosaurs in video games". I could rule out all the other pages by their titles or the publication year in their lede, and a quick check of screenshots on MobyGames confirmed that *Lost Eden* was the game we were looking for!)

Comment: YESS THIS IS IT!! THANK YOU!!! I know how I'm going to spend my weekend now! And this is the [female dinosaur](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/lost-eden/promo/promoImageId,268320/) I was thinking about.

Comment: I just looked it up, the soundtrack is on spotify too! So if you guys are curious, it was the 2nd song, Thaa's Secret, that scared me as a kid. Mainly just the beginning part because I couldn't be in the room with that music for more than the first few seconds.

Comment: @Sensoray Glad that you found what that was, and confirmed the identity of the female dinosaur! As an adventure game fan, I'm surprised I'd never heard of this one, and I may give it a try too!

Comment: @Sensoray Great, now I need to go buy and play this game ... xD

Answer (score 11):

Could this be [Blazing Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazing_Dragons_(video_game)), released on PlayStation and Sega Saturn?

> In this game, dinosaurs could speak english and some would dress in
>   clothes.

The cover of the game has a dragon wearing clothes.

> I remember going to visit a female dinosaur with a crown like object
>   around her head, she might have been part of royalty or an ambassador.

According to Wikipedia: "The player's overall quest is to become a dragon knight to compete in the grand tournament and win the heart of Princess Flame."

> There would be scenes inside a castle

Part of the game takes place inside of a "Castle Grim".

> It was a first-person view game and I believe you had to click on something to move to different areas.

The game is a point-and-click play style.

*(Never played the game--I found it by googling "video game dinosaur castle king")*

Comment: Sorry, this isn't it. Mine was a PC game. This one has a cartoony feel to it too, the one I'm thinking tried to look more realistic (the characters atleast). Thanks for trying though!